# Add rows without duplicates in python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I want to add new items to the original csv file.
The original file's ID increases by 1 each time an item is added, as shown below.

| Id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | Alpha |
| 1 | Beta |
| 2 | Gamma |
| 3 | Delta |

I want to add the following array

`items = ["Epsilon", "Beta", "Zeta"]`

to the original csv file and eliminate duplicates, which would finally look like this:

| Id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | Alpha |
| 1 | Beta |
| 2 | Gamma |
| 3 | Delta |
| 4 | Epsilon |
| 5 | Zeta |

I tried it with pandas, but the id column becomes "nan" for some reason.

```
import pandas as pd
items = ["Epsilon", "Beta", "Zeta"]
df = pd.read_csv('original.csv', index_col='Id')
for i in range(len(items)):
    df=df.append({'Id': len(df), 'Name': items[i]}, ignore_index=True)
df = df.drop_duplicates(['Name'], ignore_index=True)
df
```

I would appreciate it if you could help me with this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```py
items = ["Epsilon", "Beta", "Zeta"]

df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame({"Name": items})]).drop_duplicates(subset="Name")
df["Id"] = range(len(df))

print(df)
# df.to_csv('out.csv')
```

Prints:

```
   Id     Name
0   0    Alpha
1   1     Beta
2   2    Gamma
3   3    Delta
0   4  Epsilon
2   5     Zeta
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Id': [0, 1, 2, 3], 'Name': ['Alpha', 'Beta', 'Gamma', 'Delta']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

items = ["Epsilon", "Beta", "Zeta"]

for i in range(len(items)):
    if items[i] not in df['Name'].values:
        df = df.append({'Id': df.index[-1] + 1, 'Name': items[i]}, ignore_index=True)

print(df)
```

Results:

```
   Id  Name
0   0    Alpha
1   1     Beta
2   2    Gamma
3   3    Delta
4   4  Epsilon
5   5     Zeta
```

Note that we use `df.index[-1] + 1` to generate the new `Id` value for each item. This ensures that the `Id` values are incremented by 1 for each new item added to the dataframe.